# How to flip direction of dupli objects?

Tags: transforms, normals, geometry, instances

I want to know how to get the dupli object to flip? Examlpe: I have bolts distributed on one side of the default cube. How can I get the "bolts" to point out on the other side of the cube.
I have a mesh that I'm using for the duplication (have tried with dupli faces, and verts). I have the "bolts" placed on one side of the cube no problem, but no mater how I try to rotate the faces of the duplication mesh the bolts still face the same way. I have tried adding a mirror modifier on the duplication mesh, copying and rotating the faces but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With duplication set to verts, the objects are oriented the same as the original.

[image]

When duplication is set to faces, the objects are oriented by the face normals.

[image]

You can change the normals direction of selected faces by choosing Flip Normals under Mesh->Normals, or use the shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to set them to face out or in.

[image]

You can also turn on the display of the normals in edit mode under Mesh Display in the properties sidebar <kbd>N</kbd>.

[image]

To have the bolts displayed at the corner of the cube but still control the direction create another mesh to do the duplication with small faces in place that isn't rendered.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you scale an object by negative 1, it will reverse it on all axes.  Then you can just rotate it by 180 degrees on a single axis, and you will have essentially created an exact mirror image of an object without the hassle of a mirror modifier.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

To let the bolts appear on each side you could you would need to setup the geometry for your child object like:

[image]

Let the bolts be duplicated from a smaller object so that the dups have an offset to corners of the actual object.

[image]

The result looks like:

[image]